# Symfony command cache:clear make certain permissions to be lost

Tags: symfony, permissions, directory

I am using Symfony 2.0.12 in a Mac Os X Lion (10.7.4).

For some reason, every time I clear cache (php app/console cache:clear), the permissions of cache/* folder are lost.

The result is that I try to enter my application and it start to give me a bounch of errors like "unable to write in app/cache/dev/XXX folder".

So there starts a "fight" against the machine. No sooner I give permissions for that folder, quickly I get an error message for the next YYY folder. And that happens during about 8 or 9 folders until it's me the winner and everything apparently starts to works normally again.

Did anyone pass through this? How can I manage to conserve the permissions when clearing the cache?

Comment: how do you set the permissions for that folder? in symfony installation manual there are 3 ways to do that, and all of them should prevent this. (i.e. set permissions both for your user and the web server user)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. But that doesn't solve the problem. Using the first of the three methods mentioned in the installation manual (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) helps me just to set all the permissions with two single commands. But still happening the issue when clearing the cache... I think it's more to do with Matt's answer. Thanks again!

Comment: yes, but also there you need to know your web server user. because in the first of the commands, you set permissions for www-data, which is an example of web server user. the second `whoami` ensures your user will have permissions. so you just need to modify the first command to replace www-data for your web user. Check your httpd.conf file if you're using apache, and search for something like `User www-data`

Answer (score 2):

in the documentation there are some alternative commands on how to set up the permissions. but i dunno if they work for mac. Check the **Setting up Permissions** box.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

on my ubuntu system the following commands made the permissions permanent

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

making the webserver run as your user is not a good idea in my opinion because the webserver should not have access to your personal files and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the commands as a different user than the php process that create the cache files then this will happen. You'll either have to run the commands as the web server user, make the web server run as your user, or chown/chmod the app/cache app/logs directories after you run commands.

Comment: Uhmm... thanks a lot. That leads me to a know problem I have: I'm not even a basic user of Unix. I know that these are such basic questions, but, let me ask: How do I know the web server user? How do I manage to run the commands from a determinate user?